# CMake - Add a global build step (not specifict to any project)

Tags: cmake

Is there any way to add a "global" build step with CMake? One that is executed once per build and isn't tied to any specific project.

Adding it to the ZERO_CHECK project would work, but I can't figure out if/how that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looks like the only way to do this is to add an empty target and add the build step to it. It isn't pretty but it works.

Comment: Because it adds another project to the list. ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK are fortunately the first and last projects alphabetically, but the new target's name can be descriptive (in which case it would be between other projects alphabetically), or start with an A or Z and show up at the end or beginning, but then the name isn't descriptive. Or it can be descriptive and start with an "_", but then the naming style doesn't match.

Comment: For some IDEs, you can tidy up your solution explorer tree by setting the [`FOLDER` property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:FOLDER) on each target.

Comment: Neat, I'll have to look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not satisfied with the ["empty-target-solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603603/147808), there's the possibility to use the *install* facilities of CMake, which has built in time stamp checking to copy only new files as necessary. But then your user would [have to run the install target explicitly unless you do some tricks](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-March/043408.html) which maybe isn't what you want.

Comment: The empty target solution DOES do exactly what I need, I just have to get overy my irrational reservations about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to the top level CMakeLists.txt? Sound like you are confusing the use of CMake which is what the title suggest and how CMake projects work in VS.

What exactly is this global build step suppose to do?

Comment: It needs to copy some files that all the projects depend on. So if one developer builds projects A and B, the files need to be copied (once). If another developer bulds project C, the files need to be copied (once). So I can't add the step to all projects, because they would be copied multiple times. I can't add the step to any one project, because it might not get added as a target.

Comment: You can use the OUTPUT argument of a custom command to specify the copied files or even add a touch command to create a stamp file to make sure the files are copied only once.

Comment: Well I can get around copying the files multiple times, but then I end up with 20 projects, each of which tries to copy the files. VS's output window goes crazy. So I think adding an empty target that does the copying is the cleanest way, especially since I now know about the FOLDER propery thanks to Fraser's comment.